# How can I reset a variable before each iteration?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'd like to setup tests for a helper.

The logic is simple: before each test, I create a new item, and apply my function on it.

here is the very basic function:

```
const myTest = (item) => {
   return item.valid ? 'ok' : 'ko'
}

const createItem = () => {
  return {
    name: 'myItem',
    valid: true,
  }
}
```

And here is the test file

```
describe('products/checkStatus', () => {
  let item
  beforeEach(() => {
    item = createItem()
  })

  test('valid item', () => {
    expect(
      myTest(
        item,
      ),
    ).toBe('ok')
  })

  test('invalid item', () => {
    item.valid = false
    expect(
      myTest(
        item
      ),
    ).toBe('ko')
  })

  test('valid item again', () => {
    expect(
      myTest(
        item
      ),
    ).toBe('ok')
  })
})
```

So, first and second test will pass successfully, but the third one will fail, because it considers that `item.valid` is `false`.

How comes so ? Isn't `beforeEach` supposed to be executed bedore each test, and therefore get a fresh, valid item ?

Comment: I tried to edit it but got rejected. Does `product.valid = false` make sense? I think it should be `item.valid = false`

Comment: I just reviewed and accepted your change, thanks

Comment: Unable to reproduce https://repl.it/repls/DelayedClosedScientificcomputing I am sure your actual code is different. If you run exactly what you have posted here you'd get a `ReferenceError` because `myTest` is not `mytest`

Comment: Indeed, I iedited it so that mytest is myTest

Comment: Your code snippet works as expected. You should have checked it before posting.

Comment: Your code works fine.  P.S. This question has 3 upvotes, really?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I guess it has 3 upvotes because somehow, for some people, this code doesn't work.